# Qt accessing ExtraSelection formatting (testing)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I am trying to test my highlight_word function (below). However, I can't figure out how to access the formatting. I essentially just want to show that it is non-default. I have tried `QPlainTextEdit.extraSelections()`, but it apparently refers to destroyed objects. I have also tried `QTextCursor.charFormat().background.color()` with an appropriately positioned cursor, but only ever get `rgbf(0,0,0,1)`.

```
    def highlight_word(self, cursor: QTextCursor):
        selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
        color = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter()
        selection.format.setBackground(color)
        selection.cursor = cursor
        self.setExtraSelections([selection])
```

**UPDATE**

First, I am using PySide2, if that affects what follows.

The accepted solution works. My problem was I was writing `self.editor.extraSelections()[0].format.background().color().getRgb()`, which leads to `RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide2.QtGui.QTextCharFormat) already deleted.`. This strikes me as bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTextCursor.charFormat().background().color()` is not returning the color is because the `QTextCharFormat` is applied to the `QTextEdit.ExtraSelection`. You could add the line `selection.cursor.setCharFormat(selection.format)`, but it's not necessary. It should work if you just access the selection from `extraSelections()` and get the selection format.

Here is an example, highlight a word and then click the "Highlight" button, it will print the background RGBA. After click the "Get Selection" button, it will print the highlighted word and the background color.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.textbox = QPlainTextEdit()
        btn = QPushButton('Highlight')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.highlight_word)
        btn2 = QPushButton('Get Selection')
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.get_selections)
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(btn, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(btn2, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.textbox, 1, 0, 1, 2)

    def highlight_word(self):
        selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
        color = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter()
        selection.format.setBackground(color)
        selection.cursor = self.textbox.textCursor()
        self.textbox.setExtraSelections([selection])
        print(selection.format.background().color().getRgb())

    def get_selections(self):
        selection = self.textbox.extraSelections()[0]
        print(selection.cursor.selectedText(), selection.format.background().color().getRgb())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Got things working now. I would've sworn I had tried your exact solution in my attempts, yet here we are.